# How to access PyQT UI element from Logger Class?

Tags: python, logging, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using the following `Logger` class to receive log messages from an external python module. How to update the GUI from this class for eg. display the error message to user in UI?

```
class Logger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        print('debug : %s' % msg)
    def error(self, msg):
        print('error : %s' % msg)
```

**Edit (for clarification):** I am importing an external python module which allows listening to emitted log messages from it using `logging.Logger` instance passed to it as parameter dictionary. I am using the `Logger Class` code above to listen to these log messages in my GUI app which works fine, my question is how to display these message on GUI. I tried using `self.ui.someLabel.setText(msg)` but that is not working, I know this is a scope issue but how to get this working as I am learning python here.

Comment: Can you clarify your code structure ? You have a GUI on 1 side, and the logger on the other side ? You to communicate the logger messages to the GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

For example suppose you have initialized your mainwindow and logger in one file like this:

```
mainWindow = MainWindow()
logger = Logger()
```

The you should give a reference to mainWindow to your logger:

```
logger.mainWindow = mainWindow
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
class Logger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        self.mainWindow.ui.someLabel.setText(msg)
        print('debug : %s' % msg)
```

Another approach would be passing mainWindow instance to Logger while initializing it:

```
mainWindow = MainWindow()
logger = Logger(mainWindow)
```

then your Logger class would be something like this:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow

    def debug(self, msg):
        self.mainWindow.ui.someLabel.setText(msg)
        print('debug : %s' % msg)
```